# 404 page when creating module in Magento2

Tags: magento2

I have followed exactly [this](http://www.magesolution.com/blog/guide-to-create-a-module-in-magento-2/) to create module, but module is redirecting at 404. When I run command `php bin/magento module:enable Tutorial_Example`

> Unknown module(s): 'Tutorial_Example'

This error is shown in terminal, I think this is the reason for 404 redirection.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: which version are u using ?

Comment: use  command `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial you have followed is out of date. They introduced a `registration.php` file that you need to include in the `app/code/[Vendor]/[ModuleName]/` directory.

It looks like below code:

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[Vendor]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

Here is another [tutorial](https://www.smartiehastheanswer.co.uk/magento2/module-basics.html) that should help you get the module up and running at least.